# htaccess rewritecond, starts with and ends with matching

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Cant seem to get a redirect to work. Please consider the following:

```
 /poles/foobar.html
 /poles/foobar/doodaa.html
 /poles/foobar.html?qparam=123
 /poles/foobar/doodaa.html?qparam=123
 /poles/foobar.html?qparam=123&cat=444
 /poles/foobar/doodaa.html?qparam=123&cat=444
```

My current rule (i know it wont catch all the above...but I cant even get it to catch any of them)

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/poles 
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\.html$
 RewriteRule (.*) /poles/ [R=301,L]
```

How could I catch all possible url scenarios? They would all start with **/poles/** and end in **.html** ...or **.html?queryparams**

### UPDATE, MY .HTACCESS FILE CONTENTS, MAGENTO2 SITE:

```
      ############################################
      ## overrides deployment configuration mode value
      ## use command bin/magento deploy:mode:set to switch modes

      #   SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer

      ############################################
      ## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
      ## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
      ## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

      #    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
      #    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

      ############################################
      ## GoDaddy specific options

      #   Options -MultiViews

      ## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
      ##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
      ## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

      ############################################
      ## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

          #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
          #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

      ############################################
      ## default index file

          DirectoryIndex index.php

      <IfModule mod_php5.c>

      ############################################
      ## adjust memory limit

          php_value memory_limit 768M
          php_value max_execution_time 18000

      ############################################
      ## disable automatic session start
      ## before autoload was initialized

          php_flag session.auto_start off

      ############################################
      ## enable resulting html compression

          #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

      ###########################################
      ## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

          php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

      </IfModule>

      <IfModule mod_php7.c>

      ############################################
      ## adjust memory limit

          php_value memory_limit 768M
          php_value max_execution_time 18000

      ############################################
      ## disable automatic session start
      ## before autoload was initialized

          php_flag session.auto_start off

      ############################################
      ## enable resulting html compression

          #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

      ###########################################
      ## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

          php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

      </IfModule>

      <IfModule mod_security.c>
      ###########################################
      ## disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

          SecFilterEngine Off
          SecFilterScanPOST Off
      </IfModule>

      <IfModule mod_deflate.c>

      ############################################
      ## enable apache served files compression
      ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

          # Insert filter on all content
          ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
          # Insert filter on selected content types only
          #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json image/svg+xml

          # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
          #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

          # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
          #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

          # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
          #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

          # Don't compress images
          #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

          # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
          #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

      </IfModule>

      <IfModule mod_ssl.c>

      ############################################
      ## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

          SSLOptions StdEnvVars

      </IfModule>

      ############################################
      ## workaround for Apache 2.4.6 CentOS build when working via ProxyPassMatch with HHVM (or any other)
      ## Please, set it on virtual host configuration level

      ##    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
      ############################################

      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

      ############################################
      ## enable rewrites

          Options +FollowSymLinks
          RewriteEngine on

      ############################################
      ## you can put here your magento root folder
      ## path relative to web root

          #RewriteBase /magento/

      ############################################
      ## workaround for HTTP authorization
      ## in CGI environment

          RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

      ############################################
      ## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
          RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

      ############################################
      ## redirect for mobile user agents

          #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
          #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
          #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

      ############################################
      ## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

      ############################################
      ## rewrite everything else to index.php

          RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

      </IfModule>


      ############################################
      ## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
      ## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

          AddDefaultCharset Off
          #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
          AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html

      <IfModule mod_expires.c>

      ############################################
      ## Add default Expires header
      ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

          ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
          ExpiresByType text/html A0
          ExpiresByType text/plain A0

      </IfModule>

      ###########################################
      ## Deny access to root files to hide sensitive application information
          RedirectMatch 403 /\.git

          <Files composer.json>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files composer.lock>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files .gitignore>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files .htaccess>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files .htaccess.sample>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files .php_cs>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files .travis.yml>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files CHANGELOG.md>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files CONTRIBUTING.md>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files COPYING.txt>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files Gruntfile.js>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files LICENSE.txt>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files nginx.conf.sample>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files package.json>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files php.ini.sample>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files README.md>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>
          <Files magento_umask>
              order allow,deny
              deny from all
          </Files>

      # For 404s and 403s that aren't handled by the application, show plain 404 response
      ErrorDocument 404 /pub/errors/404.php
      ErrorDocument 403 /pub/errors/404.php

      ################################
      ## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
      ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

          #FileETag none

      # ######################################################################
      # # INTERNET EXPLORER                                                  #
      # ######################################################################

      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
      # | Document modes                                                     |
      # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

      # Force Internet Explorer 8/9/10 to render pages in the highest mode
      # available in the various cases when it may not.
      #
      # https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/#ie8
      #
      # (!) Starting with Internet Explorer 11, document modes are deprecated.
      # If your business still relies on older web apps and services that were
      # designed for older versions of Internet Explorer, you might want to
      # consider enabling `Enterprise Mode` throughout your company.
      #
      # https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625.aspx#docmode
      # http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/04/02/stay-up-to-date-with-enterprise-mode-for-internet-explorer-11.aspx

      <IfModule mod_headers.c>

          Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"

          # `mod_headers` cannot match based on the content-type, however,
          # the `X-UA-Compatible` response header should be send only for
          # HTML documents and not for the other resources.

          <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
              Header unset X-UA-Compatible
          </FilesMatch>

      </IfModule>




      # CUSTOM 301 REDIRECTS
      # --------------------------------------------------------- ##


      # Custom eyelets category query param url redirects
      # -------------------------------------------------

      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/eyelets-3.html?(.*) 
      RewriteCond %{query_string} ^cat=233
      RewriteRule (.*) /eyelets/plastic-eyelets/? [R=301,L]

      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/eyelets-3.html?(.*) 
      RewriteCond %{query_string} ^cat=234
      RewriteRule (.*) /eyelets/metal-eyelets/? [R=301,L]



      # Custom poles category query param url redirects
      # -------------------------------------------------

      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/poles.html?(.*) 
      RewriteCond %{query_string} ^range=251
      RewriteRule (.*) /poles/? [R=301,L]



      # Custom track category query param url redirects
      # -------------------------------------------------

      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/track.html?(.*) 
      RewriteCond %{query_string} ^cat=104
      RewriteRule (.*) /tracks/plastic-track/? [R=301,L]

      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/track.html?(.*) 
      RewriteCond %{query_string} ^cat=951
      RewriteRule (.*) /tracks/metal-track/? [R=301,L]

      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/track.html?(.*) 
      RewriteCond %{query_string} ^cat=95&range=5391
      RewriteRule (.*) /tracks/metal-track/vogue/? [R=301,L]



      # Category url redirects
      # -------------------------------------------------

      Redirect 301 /poles.html /poles
      Redirect 301 /track.html /tracks
      Redirect 301 /curtrain-track.html /tracks
      Redirect 301 /net-suspension-products.html /net-suspension
      Redirect 301 /tiebacks-and-trimmings.html /tiebacks
      Redirect 301 /brassware-1.html /brassware
      Redirect 301 /eyelets-3.html /eyelets
      Redirect 301 /blinds.html /blinds/retail-blinds
      Redirect 301 /roman-blind-systems.html /blinds/roman-blind-systems
      Redirect 301 /shower-rail-products.html /net-suspension/shower-rail-products
      Redirect 301 /accessories-and-sundries.html /accessories
      Redirect 301 /panel-track.html /tracks/metal-track/panel-track
      Redirect 301 /valance-track.html /tracks/metal-track/aluminium-valance-rail





      # Subcategory url redirects - DOES NOT WORK
      # -------------------------------------------------
      # eg: /poles/foobar.html
      # eg: /poles/foobar/doodaa.html
      # eg: /poles/foobar.html?cat=4
      # eg: /poles/foobar/doodaa.html?cat=4

      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^/poles 
      RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\.html$
      RewriteRule (.*) /poles/? [R=301,L]






      # Page/Section url redirects
      # -------------------------------------------------

      Redirect 301 /downloads /resources
      Redirect 301 /about-us /about-us.html
      Redirect 301 /specialoffers /blog
      Redirect 301 /testimonials /blog
      Redirect 301 /contact-us /contact
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be what you're trying to achieve:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/poles/.*\.html$
RewriteRule ^ /poles/? [R=301,L]
```

You nearly had it. The caret (^) means the start of the string, so needed removing on your second condition. They could also be combined. The query string isn't part of the match in REQUEST_URI so any query string will match. The question mark in the RewriteRule removes any query string.

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can upvote my answer two now if you like. You can do it now you have over 15 reputation. Using the little up arrow next to the tick. It gives me a bit more reputation for the answer and shows you approve of it.

Comment: Think i spoke too soon. Its not working right.

/poles/some-poles.html goes to 404.

Could this be an apache version issue with the given code?
Ive been removing other rules...so only the rule you gave is present, and does not work right.

Other simple redirect rules...matching whole urls are working fine.

Comment: Other entries in the htaccess:

     Options +FollowSymLinks
     RewriteEngine on

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

Comment: Please post your full .htaccess file in an edit to the question.

Comment: Updated the question with htaccess file contens.

Comment: Thanks. And sorry it's my mistake. Must have been half asleep writing this! It needs changing to REQUEST_URI as I already thought it was using, and talked about in the explanation. Please use the updated rewrite code.

Comment: I dont see any updated rewrite code? It still says THE_REQUEST.....I now have:   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/poles/.*\.html$
RewriteRule ^ /poles/? [R=301,L]

But all the test urls such as: http://foobar.com/poles/foobar.html go to 404   :(

Comment: You don't need this [R=301,L] just [L] will be better

Comment: Not true Kevin, the R=301 is what makes it become a 301 redirect, rather than an internal rewrite. Totally different, one goes back to the browser and the other serves that internally rewritten URL as the original URL. A brief explanation sure, but that’s the basic idea.